# how can I improve performance if I have used primary key on a guid column?

Tags: sql, performance, indexing, primary-key, guid

i got a table with half a million rows.

the primary key is the guid column .

I found the query `select * from T where id ='xxxx'` is very slow .

what should I do to improve performance ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can, I would recommend the following:

- drop the existing primary key - especially if it's the clustering key, too (which is it by default)
- add a new `INT IDENTITY` column

  ```
  ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable ADD NewID INT IDENTITY(1,1)
  ```
- make that INT field the primary / clustering key:

  ```
  ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable
    ADD CONSTRAINT PK_YourTable PRIMARY KEY(NewID)
  ```

A primary key (or more precisely: **clustering key**) on a GUID column is a horrible idea, leads to massive index fragmentation, and thus kills your SELECT performance.

As [Kimberly Tripp](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/GUIDs-as-PRIMARY-KEYs-andor-the-clustering-key.aspx) - the Queen of Indexing - and others have stated a great many times - a GUID as the clustering key isn't optimal, since due to its randomness, it will lead to massive page and index fragmentation and to generally bad performance.

Yes, I know - there's `newsequentialid()` in SQL Server 2005 and up - but even that is not truly and fully sequential and thus also suffers from the same problems as the GUID - just a bit less prominently so.

Then there's another issue to consider: the clustering key on a table will be added to each and every entry on each and every non-clustered index on your table as well - thus you really want to make sure it's as small as possible. Typically, an INT with 2+ billion rows should be sufficient for the vast majority of tables - and compared to a GUID as the clustering key, you can save yourself hundreds of megabytes of storage on disk and in server memory.

Quick calculation - using INT vs. GUID as Primary and Clustering Key:

- Base Table with 1'000'000 rows (3.8 MB vs. 15.26 MB)
- 6 nonclustered indexes (22.89 MB vs. 91.55 MB)

**TOTAL: 25 MB vs. 106 MB** - and that's just on a single table!

Some more food for thought - excellent stuff by Kimberly Tripp - read it, read it again, digest it! It's the SQL Server indexing gospel, really.

- [GUIDs as PRIMARY KEY and/or clustered key](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/GUIDs-as-PRIMARY-KEYs-andor-the-clustering-key.aspx)
- [The clustered index debate continues](http://sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/The-Clustered-Index-Debate-Continues.aspx)
- [Ever-increasing clustering key - the Clustered Index Debate..........again!](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/Ever-increasing-clustering-key-the-Clustered-Index-Debateagain!.aspx)
- [Disk space is cheap - that's **not** the point!](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/Disk-space-is-cheap.aspx)

Comment: Just to be clear, this advice and the related advice in the article by Kimberley Tripp applies only to CLUSTERED INDEXES in SQL Server - something not mentioned in the original question. A clustered index is not the same thing as a PRIMARY KEY and it's not certain if SQL Server is the DBMS in use here. I mention this because the advice "drop the existing primary key" is not in itself a sensible suggestion just because your primary key happens to be a GUID - not if you value the uniqueness of that column!

Comment: @dportas: yes, true - but the primary key in SQL Server **is the clustering key by default** - unless you specifically **not** make it the clustering key. I would guess in at least 85% of cases, PK = CK

Comment: @marc_s, I would put it more precisely this way: the clustered key is exactly what you choose the clustered key to be when you create it. Ditto the primary key. Keys and indexes are different things and I don't think it's a good idea to encourage confusion between the two, especially when the OP asked about the former and not the latter.

Comment: @dportas: yes - if you even **know** that there's a PK and a CK - a surprising number of "DB Developers" don't even know that..... and if you don't actively prevent it, SQL Server will put your CK on your PK - which is why it's that way in at least 85% of all cases.....

Comment: @marc_s, maybe you are right. But if even someone with your level of reputation fails to distinguish between the two then how can we expect the less experienced users to learn any better?

Comment: @dportas: I'm **very well** aware of the difference - thank you very much. I tried not to confuse the OP, but from the question, I was lead to believe most likely he also has the CK on your GUID column and that's causing the major performance problems (no surprise, really). Basically, I assumed that the OP said "primary key" because that's what he knows, but really, in the background, it's the CK that's causing the issues - thus my explanation

Comment: @marc_s, apologies, I didn't mean to imply that you were unaware of the difference, just that your reply didn't make the distinction plain. So when you said "drop the existing primary key" and then specified creating the PRIMARY KEY as an INT, what you *really* meant was "drop the clustered index and make it an INT". I think you could have made that clearer.